# Alamofire: Image download request issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I'm new in the Swift, I am using `Alamofire` framework in my project, I am facing the following issue while giving the request for download image, I am using following code:

```
let imageURL = Constant.BaseAPI_URL + "/" + driver.driverProfile
Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).response() {
        (_, _, data, _) in
        let image = UIImage(data: data! as! NSData)
        deiverProfileImageView.image = image
}
```

**Issue :**

[Click Here For Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKx0a.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let imageURL = Constant.BaseAPI_URL + "/" + driver.driverProfile


    Alamofire.download(imageURL).responseData { response in
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            deiverProfileImageView.image = image
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
let imageURL = Constant.BaseAPI_URL + "/" + driver.driverProfile
Alamofire.request(imageURL).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
   if let imageData = response.data
   {
        deiverProfileImageView.image = imageData
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

let imageUrl = "www.your_url.com"

```
Alamofire.download(imageUrl).responseData {
  response in
      if let data = response.result.value {
           let image = UIImage(data: data)
           ProfileImage.image = image
       }
}
```

**or**

The easiest way according to me will be using SDWebImage

Add this to your pod file

```
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
```

Run pod install

Now import SDWebImage

```
      import SDWebImage
```

Now for setting image from url

```
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.domain/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

It will show placeholder image but when image is downloaded it will show  the image from url .Your app will never crash

This are the main feature of SDWebImage

Categories for UIImageView, UIButton, MKAnnotationView adding web image and cache management

**An asynchronous image downloader**

An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

A background image decompression

A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times

A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again

A guarantee that main thread will never be blocked
Performances!

Use GCD and ARC

To know more https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage